# execute procedures from column in table

Tags: sql, oracle, while-loop, execute, procedures

Please help me with executing procedures in ORACLE.

I have table with 3 columns:

```
Create table PG_TABLE_1 
(ID number(3),
PROCEDURE varchar2(15),
STATUS varchar2(4));

insert into PG_TABLE_1 values ('1','PROC_1','OK');
insert into PG_TABLE_1 values ('2','PROC_2','WAIT');
insert into PG_TABLE_1 values ('3','PROC_3','WAIT');
insert into PG_TABLE_1 values ('4','PROC_4','WAIT');
```

PROC_1, PROC_2, PROC_3, PROC_4 are names of real procedures.

How can I write code with LOOP, which:

- get rows from TABLE_1 where STATUS='WAIT' ... so rows 2,3,4
- choose first name of procedure (first smaller id) ... so "PROC_2"
- execute PROC_2
- change status in row 2 from "WAIT" to "OK"
- and then PROC_3 etc.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You will have to use dynamic SQL to construct the execute statements. Put it in a while loop to iterate over the rows in the table. Oh, by the way, the whole thing is a terrible idea.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using the Oracle scheduler and chains to do all of this? A chain where each step is dependent on the execution of hte previous step would do the same thing in a manner which is easily supported. You'd also get all the logs for free.

Comment: This is only my idea, because, when I will have 30 procedures and each of them will execute in another day or hour, I thought that Scheduler is not so good idea (or I am wrong?). I have procedures with executing in each day, next with executing in each Monday or Tuesday or .. each first day in Month, first workday in Month and 5th workday in quarter etc. My idea is that I want generate for each day only procedures which will execute in this day (PG_TABLE_1) and then executing them. Please, when you have another good idea for solution my problem, tell me.

Answer (score -1):

Yup, I agree with @Anand you will have to make use of dynamic query

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PG_TABLE_1 WHERE STATUS = 'WAIT')
BEGIN
 SELECT TOP 1 @PROC =  PROCEDURE FROM PG_TABLE_1 WHERE STATUS = 'WAIT'

 SET @SQL = @SQL + @PROC

 EXEC (@SQL)

 UPDATE PG_TABLE_1 SET STATUS = 'OK' WHERE PROCEDURE = @PROC

END
```

Also please try to change the column names of **Procedure** and **Status**

Comment: This is T-SQL and not PL/SQL so won't compile on an Oracle database.